# how to send a message on a typescript websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, websocket

I have an angular application needing to subscribe to a websocket for incoming data.

On the angular side, in a service  I have

```
setContextChannel(channel) {
    this.contextWS = new WebSocket(channel);
    that = this;
    this.contextWS.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log('ws', event.data);
        that.patientID = event.data;
    };

    this.contextWS.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log('ws error', event);
    }
}
```

and on the mock server side, I have a typescript node server that creates the socket as follows:

```
import {Server} from "ws";
var wsServer: Server = new Server({port: 8085});
console.log('ws on 8085');
wsServer.on('connection',websocket => websocket.send('first pushed message'));//////
```

my question is how to use the wsServer to send messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you asking about. This line is correct:

```
wsServer.on('connection',websocket => websocket.send('first pushed message'));
```

If you want to keep sending messages to all connected clients, you need to either use the property wsServer.clients to send messages to each connected client, or store the references to each connected client (the `websocket` variable in your code) in an array and then send the messages to each client using forEach().

Take a look at this code sample: https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/blob/master/chapter8/http_websocket_samples/server/bids/bid-server.ts

Comment: thanks what I was looking for is listed in your link. websocket.on('message', is what I was looking for